# Composite UI with Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: asp.net, microservices, blazor, webassembly

I am starting to architecture system according to the Microservices Architecture. I will use Blazor WebAssembly on the UI level and I want to create proper UI according to the Composite UI or Micro Frontends approach.

I know that there is a Modular UI approach in general, and one possible implementation is by using Oqtane framework. Also, for the ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor there is BlazorComponentBus library which helps to implement communication between components. Still, I don't want to have ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor and I wouldn't like to depend on the external framework. I would rather rely on my own Composite UI architecture/implementation. My UI will also use Fluxor (Redux Pattern).

Has anyone tried to create Composite UI with Blazor WASM? Do you think Fluxor can be used in order to implement proper communication between components? Any experience or suggestion?